# Add DNS suffixes to a Sonicwall PRO2040 firewall?

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, sonicwall

I want to have our network pass out DNS suffixes with the DHCP assignments, so that we don't need to add them to the TCP/IP settings on each computer.

Our DHCP is not being handled by an actual server box, but by our Sonicwall firewall, which is a PRO 2040. Can this firewall be set up to append DNS suffixes?

Thanks!

**05/21 13:29** - searching through [the manual](http://www.sonicwall.com/downloads/SonicWALL_PRO_2040_Getting_Started_Guide.pdf) yields no results about suffixes, which is why I'm hoping maybe someone knows definitely that it cannot be done, or has a way to do it.

**05/21 15:53** Our SonicWALL is running SonicOS Standard 3.0.0.1-31s on ROM SonicROM 2.1.0.0.

Comment: and what does the manual say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you have a "Domain Name" textbox on the DNS/WINS tab for the scope configuration?  That should do it.  otherwise you could specify Option Object #15 (Domain Name) on your scope.

That said, the PRO2040 I have access to is running SonicOS Enhanced (4.2.1.0-20e).

Comment: It took a little rooting around but this was there. It was under `Networking > DHCP` then edit the DHCP scope and in there was the DNS/WINS tab. Thanks for the help afrazier!